# Use of "be" or "are"

Tags: verbs, tenses

What's the correct form?

"Fabrication cannot resume before corrective actions *be* taken."

or

"Fabrication cannot resume before corrective actions *are* taken."

Tks!

Comment: Both are grammatical. To work out which is ‘correct’, you’ll need to explain what you intend the statement to say.

Comment: @Lawrence, you got me. I would say this is kind of a "conditional" statement: "_If corrective actions are not taken, fabrication cannot resume_" would be a different (yet a bit awkward) way of saying it.

Comment: In that case, go with “are”.

Comment: By the way, the rephrasing with “if” isn’t awkward.

Comment: @Lawrence, the rephrasing sounds a bit Yoda to me, but I'm not a native speaker. I wonder if there's a general or quasi-general rule saying when one should use "are" or "be". Both sound so well to me! I originally used "are", but then an inner voice told me "be" was the correct tense. Go figure. Thanks!

Comment: Would _until_ work better than "before"?

Comment: @Cascabel, good point. I don't see a big difference, but I would intuitively go with "_before_".

Comment: I have noticed that some native-Spanish speakers struggle with _until_...not sure about Portuguese...I think most native speakers would use "until" in this case. i.e. "Fabrication cannot resume _until_ corrective actions are taken."

Comment: English rarely uses subjunctive forms, especially not with _if_ clauses.